# I want to push a Python app to Heroku on Windows 10, but i get "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, django, gcc, heroku, mod-wsgi

I enter `git push heroku master` into the command prompt and all goes well for a while then...

```
           WARNING: The Python installation you are using does not appear to have
           been installed with a shared library, or in the case of MacOS X, as a
           framework. Where these are not present, the compilation of mod_wsgi may
           fail, or if it does succeed, will result in extra memory being used by
           all processes at run time as a result of the static library needing to
           be loaded in its entirety to every process. It is highly recommended
           that you reinstall the Python installation being used from source code,
           supplying the '--enable-shared' option to the 'configure' script when
           configuring the source code prior to building and installing it.
```

then...

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/mod_wsgi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/mod_wsgi.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           src/server/mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_socket_sendv’:
           src/server/mod_wsgi.c:10966:44: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression [-Wsign-compare]
                                (nvec < iov_max ? nvec : (int)iov_max));
                                                       ^
           src/server/mod_wsgi.c: In function ‘wsgi_scan_headers’:
           src/server/mod_wsgi.c:11125:30: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional expression [-Wsign-compare]
                buflen = buffer ? buflen : sizeof(x);
                                         ^
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_memory.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_memory.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_daemon.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_daemon.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_server.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_server.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_metrics.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_metrics.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_stream.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_stream.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_convert.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_convert.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_restrict.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_restrict.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_apache.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_apache.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_buckets.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_buckets.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_logger.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_logger.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_validate.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_validate.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_thread.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_thread.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.7m -c src/server/wsgi_interp.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_interp.o -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apache/include -I. -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr/include/apr-1 -I/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/src/packages/apr-util/include/apr-1 -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread
           gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/mod_wsgi.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_memory.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_daemon.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_server.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_metrics.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_stream.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_restrict.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_apache.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_buckets.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_logger.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_validate.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_thread.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/server/wsgi_interp.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -L/app/.heroku/python/lib -L/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-linux -lpython3.7m
           /usr/bin/ld: /app/.heroku/python/lib/libpython3.7m.a(ceval.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_PyRuntime' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
           /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
           collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
           error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

           ----------------------------------------
       Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yla81xqj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oxraezk2/mod-wsgi/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I have tried `pip install gcc` to no avail and I don't even know if gcc is the real issue. I am trying to learn how to use Heroku and Python with hopes of later deploying a django app (which I have already created) via Heroku.

Comment: Have you added the python buildpack to your heroku dyno?  Can you link to a minimal, reproduceable example?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example